# I'm created my own bot, used discord.py (python)

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I'm making my own discord bot and asked myself this question. How to remake this code so that the bot sends an embed message (with a bar on the left) instead of the usual one.
It's my cod:

```
@bot.command()
async def print(ctx, *args):
    
    response = ""
    for arg in args:
        response = response + " " + arg
    
await ctx.channel.send(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use discord.embed

```
@bot.command()
async def print(ctx, *args):
    desc = ""
    for arg in args:
        desc = desc + " " + arg
    embed=discord.Embed(title="<Your title>", description=desc, color=<Your color>)
    
await ctx.channel.send(embed)
```

This should let you send your args in an embed, then just change formatting in `desc`